# Setting up negative to positive counts for time

Tags: stata

If there is a data set that has months and each person has a different month of starting a job. For example:

```
person         date       date_started      date_count
  Tim        1/1/2000       3/1/2000           -2
  Tim        2/1/2000       3/1/2000           -1
  Tim        3/1/2000       3/1/2000            0
  John       1/1/2000       7/1/2000           -6
  John       2/1/2000       7/1/2000           -5
  John       3/1/2000       7/1/2000           -4
  John       4/1/2000       7/1/2000           -3
  John       5/1/2000       7/1/2000           -2
  John       6/1/2000       7/1/2000           -1
  John       7/1/2000       7/1/2000            0
  John       8/1/2000       7/1/2000            1
  John       9/1/2000       7/1/2000            2
  John      10/1/2000       7/1/2000            3
  Mary       3/1/2000       3/1/2000            0
  Mary       4/1/2000       3/1/2000            1
```

What is the most efficient way to get the `date_count` column? I also have a column that is 1 in your first month and 0 otherwise. I rather use that in making the `date_count`

Comment: What have you tried? Try differencing year-month date variables (look for `ym()` under the `date` help file).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the optimal way, but I think it should work:

```
/* convert your dates to Stata's date format from strings */
gen date2=daily(date,"MDY");
gen date_started2=daily(date_started,"MDY");
format date2 date_started2 %td;

/* this is the main code */
gen before = date_started2>date2;
bys person before: egen date_count2 = rank(abs(date_started2 - date2));
replace date_count2 = date_count2 - 1 if before==0;
replace date_count2 = -date_count2 if before==1;
drop before;
```

**Edit:**

Mea culpa. I completely misunderstood your question to mean that you wanted a countdown to start date for each person-observation event. You actually want something much simpler:

> gen date_count2=mofd(daily(date,"MDY")) - mofd(daily(date_started,"MDY"));

This assumes you are working with date and date_started that are stores as string variables. The daily() converts to Stata date format, and mofd() converts to calendar months. Then it's just the difference.

Comment: This does work but I believe the second to last line `before==1` should be `before==0`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what the difficulty is here. The question seems poorly explained to me.

1. You mention months, but your example shows daily dates, so the role of months in the problem is a mystery.
2. The variable you want is just the difference between two daily dates. So long as you have two daily date variables (Dimitriy explains how to get those from string dates), it is just a subtraction.

(Added later) My uncertainty shows what happens when one assumes on an international list that local conventions are universal. There are two conventions easily confused, showing dates as day/month/year and showing dates as month/day/year. Evidently you are using the second convention. If so, the problem is to convert from daily dates to monthly dates using `mofd()`; then as said it is a subtraction.